# What is the complexity of the following algorithm?

Tags: java, complexity-theory, hamiltonian-cycle

This algorithm solves Hamiltonian path problem. `G` is a unoriented graph, `v` starting vertex, 
`G.size()` size of the graph, `G.get(v).gV` all the neighbor verices of the current vertex.

```
static private void dfs(HashMap<Integer, Virsune> G, int v) {
    path.push(v);
    // add v to the current path
    onPath[v] = true;

    if (path.size() == G.size()) {
        System.out.println(path);

        Integer[] tmp = new Integer[G.size()];
        System.arraycopy(path.toArray(), 0, tmp, 0, path.size());
        hamPaths.add(tmp);
    }

    for (int w : G.get(v).gV) {
        if (!onPath[w]) {
            dfs(G, w);
        }
    }

    path.pop();
    onPath[v] = false;

} 
   // main method
   dfs(G,0);
```

Can I just say that complexity of this algorithm is O(n!) ?

Comment: What would make it O(n!) how many times are we looking at each node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is algorithm is enumerating all the paths of the graph.

If you're enumerating all the paths in a graph, this should give you a hint at the runtime. In a complete graph, there are indeed n! paths, so this is a lower bound.  I'll leave it to you to say if it's an upper bound as well.

FWIW - the problem is solvable in O(2^n)

Comment: Wouldn't n! be the upper bound? I would think the lower bound would just be n.